# Beamer header vertical section horizontal subsection

Tags: beamer, header-footer

I am new to beamer customization.

I am trying to have the following header.

|  |  |  |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Section 1 | Subsection 1.1 | Subsection 1.2 |
| Section 2 | Subsection 2.1 | Subsection 2.2 |
| Section 3 | Subsection 3.1 | Subsection 3.2 |

keeping the current chapter and current section highlighted, the rest shaded but visible.

This is my best attempt, very far from the goal. I still miss what each custom part really does.

```
\makeatletter
\setbeamertemplate{headline}
{%
    \begin{beamercolorbox}[wd=\paperwidth,colsep=1.5pt]{upper separation line head}
    \end{beamercolorbox}
%    \begin{beamercolorbox}[wd=\paperwidth,ht=2.5ex,dp=1.125ex,%
%      leftskip=.3cm,rightskip=.3cm plus1fil]{title in head/foot}
%      \usebeamerfont{title in head/foot}\insertshorttitle
%    \end{beamercolorbox}
    \begin{beamercolorbox}[wd=\paperwidth,ht=2.5ex,dp=1.125ex,%
      leftskip=.3cm,rightskip=.3cm plus1fil]{section in head/foot}
      \usebeamerfont{section in head/foot}%
        \setbox\beamer@tempbox=\hbox{\insertsectionhead}%
      \insertsectionhead
    \end{beamercolorbox}
    \begin{beamercolorbox}[wd=\paperwidth,ht=2.5ex,dp=1.125ex,%
      leftskip=.3cm,rightskip=.3cm plus1fil]{subsection in head/foot}
      \usebeamerfont{subsection in head/foot}%
        \setbox\beamer@tempbox=\hbox{\insertsubsectionhead}%
      \insertsubsectionhead
    \end{beamercolorbox}
    \begin{beamercolorbox}[wd=\paperwidth,colsep=1.5pt]{lower separation line head}
    \end{beamercolorbox}
} 
\makeatother
```